# Library projects not recognized in Android with latest android tools/sdk updates

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, build-tools

I have basically just downloaded the newest android and eclipse bundle from Google, and upgraded the sdks to the newest versions. As well as installed the adt plugin.

Well... now all content of any library projects wont get recognized.

They are included fine as Libraries, but I get a red x whenever a class tries to reference anything from a library project. (Edit: the problem is that any library reference cannot be resolved.)

Nothing works. Cleaning, restructuring, restarting. The jars from the Library projects aren't being included in the bin folders anymore, and I can understand that that is from the new build system upgrade. But this also break everything!

Has anyone had a similar problem, and hopefully a solution?

(I am also running Windows 7 64 bit)

Comment: Take a [look](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-2.htm)

Comment: A red "x" means there is a statement in your "Problems" view. What is the actual problem? Go to "Show View" then "Problems"

Comment: "The import blah.blah cannot be resolved." despite it being a referenced library.

Answer (score -1):

whatever library project you are using should have common support v4 jar file in lib folder,
so get the updated support v4 libary and replace all old v4 libary with that updated one.

still getting a error then post your logcat log